# Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (2, 1)

Tags: python, pandas

**A:**

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({"a": [['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1, 0, [6.0689999999999884]], ['*', 6.0690000000000168, 1, 0, [6.0690000000000168]], ['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1,0, [6.0689999999999884]]], "b": 12}, index=[0, 1, 2])
                           a   b
0  [*, 6.069, 1, 0, [6.069]]  12
1  [*, 6.069, 1, 0, [6.069]]  12
2  [*, 6.069, 1, 0, [6.069]]  12
```

Yes, 3 rows are created, but I want to create one row.

**B:**

I try in following way but it is not working.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({"a": [['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1, 0, [6.0689999999999884]], ['*', 6.0690000000000168, 1, 0, [6.0690000000000168]], ['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1,0, [6.0689999999999884]]], "b": 12}, index=[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 226, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 363, in _init_dict
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5168, in _arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3916, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3882, in construction_error
    passed,implied))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (2, 1)
```

**C**

It is working in following way by created list of  list.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({"a": [[['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1, 0, [6.0689999999999884]], ['*', 6.0690000000000168, 1, 0, [6.0690000000000168]], ['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1,0, [6.0689999999999884]]]], "b": 12}, index=[0])
                                                   a   b
0  [[*, 6.069, 1, 0, [6.069]], [*, 6.069, 1, 0, [...  12
>>>
```

But my input like above B.

So what to do ?

Comment: If you want to create just 1 row, create in `C` style. Whats your question?

Answer (score 4):

If **C** is working, then, why aren't you using **C** ?
When you say 'my input like above B' do you mean you have a variable, let's say, data, like this :

```
data = [['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1, 0, [6.0689999999999884]], ['*', 6.0690000000000168, 1, 0, [6.0690000000000168]], ['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1,0, [6.0689999999999884]]]
```

?

Then, why don't you simply use this :

```
pd.DataFrame({"a": [data], "b": 12}, index=[0])
```

I'm not sure if I fully understood what you want.

Comment: I want to create dataframe with one row, and input is `[ ["*", 6.6, 1, 0, [6.6]], ...]` because I want to change in all place in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your data frame to one row after the creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1, 0, [6.0689999999999884]], ['*', 6.0690000000000168, 1, 0, [6.0690000000000168]], ['*', 6.0689999999999884, 1,0, [6.0689999999999884]]], "b": 12}, index=[0, 1, 2])

df.groupby('b').a.apply(list).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: ok, can u tell me one thng, How to insert row in existing Dataframe ? means I have dataframe with 10K rows and I want to add row in every 100 multiply places. Currently I am slicing Dataframe with interval of 100 and concatenate with dataframe which of one row(which I want to insert)  and again concatenate remaining dataframe.

Comment: Seems to me, that is one way to insert rows into a data frame. Could also do `df.loc[newIndex] = Series object representing one row`. So you want to insert this one row data frame into another data frame?

Comment: not from other dataframe, I have data in list or dictionary format, Can u show me by simple example? If we insert row in 100 place then where will go existing data of 100 row ?

Comment: Still, I am not sure what your real situation is. But here is how I would append a separate row to an existing data frame. `df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3], 'y': [2,3,4]}); df.append({'x': 3, 'y': 4}, ignore_index=True)`